# Get the value of the data attribute when an element is clicked on using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that is very simple. basically I need to get the value of a data attribute when an element is clicked on.

I'm using the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', ".MyLi", function (e) {
  var cont = $(this).attr('data-cont');
  alert(cont);
});
```

This works BUT with an issue.

If you run the following code in the fiddle, you will see that it will show the `data-cont` value in the `alert()`; but when I click on the **SUB MENU** it will first show the sub menu `data-cont` in the alert() and then it shows the `MY MENU` `data-cont` which is its parent!

```js
$(document).on('click', ".MyLi", function (e) {
  var cont = $(this).attr('data-cont');
  alert(cont);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="MyLi" data-cont="MY MENU ">
  <a><i></i>&nbsp;MY MENU</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="MyLi" data-cont="MY SUBMENU">
      <a><i></i>&nbsp;MY SUBMENU</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I only need the value of the `data-cont` of the element that is clicked on!

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is called bubbling/propagation of events. 
`event.stopPropagation()` is what you are looking for

This stops events to bubble up to top elements or traverse down to lower elements under the same `selector` `.MyLi` in your case.

Rad more about [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

```js
$(document).on('click', ".MyLi", function(e){

  e.stopPropagation();  
  var cont = $(this).attr('data-cont');
  
  alert(cont);

  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="MyLi" data-cont="MY MENU ">
<a>
<i></i>&nbsp;
MY MENU 
</a>
<ul>
<li class="MyLi" data-cont="MY SUBMENU"><a>
<i></i>&nbsp;
MY SUBMENU</a></li>
</ul></li>
```

Comment: Nice one. that did it.

Comment: sure George. I will have to wait for 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

George's answer is good but just for you to know : it's a regular behaviour.

`(document).on('click', ".MyLi", function(e){ ...` targets, as you asked, all elements with `.MyLi` class.

And you gave the same `class` to the MENU and the SUBMENU. So it returns both `data-attribute`.